# how to rotate image on xyz axis along with phone sensors in android

Tags: android

I am currently trying out to rotate/animate a image in XYZ axis along with phone sensors.like if we rotate a phone in x direction then image will be rotate in x axis,same like y and z axis. but i didn't found any solution for it. please help me.

Comment: Use SensorManager.

Comment: but how to set on image ? i want to rotate an image in xyz axis and SensorManager  only rotate image in only x and y axis.i have also used 3*3 matrix but i dont know how to set matrix on image to rotate in xyz axis.

Comment: Check [this](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/content/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation.html)